# Cloned repo does not contain .\.git\object files

Tags: git

I have created a git repo and added many files to it. After pushing it to GitHub and cloning back to another directory, it does not contain the ..git\objects files expected. Why is that? Does something cause them to be created?

```
C:>git --version
git version 2.24.1.windows.2
```

In the .git\objects directory there are almost 1,000 files.

```
....
.\.git\objects\f8\f52e48d8d7e2908c46c56556b83e98d0298351
.\.git\objects\f9\55d8ce563434be03cb82fb58c36d4da4ac38df
.\.git\objects\f9\6534128e7beac05352197f3b8fe3c718bbd305
.\.git\objects\f9\e501e444744fbc883a5b98a1556fba885f2ade
.\.git\objects\f9\f90be9cca6f6f5025ed94951912a4737b0c6d2
.\.git\objects\fa\24dcc4164dfd6984320e645730e796700be9df
.\.git\objects\fa\84dfe81cf05281c5469810681d9ed31802a2b0
...
```

I pushed the repo to a GitHub server.
I cloned the repo to a different directory on my machine.
The ..git\objects directory contains only:

```
.\.git\objects\info
.\.git\objects\pack
.\.git\objects\pack\pack-3e89ef1c1cab090340be3f33c9147a8bbb0fb095.idx
.\.git\objects\pack\pack-3e89ef1c1cab090340be3f33c9147a8bbb0fb095.pack
```

Why does it not contain the many files from the original repo?

Comment: Loose objects are gathered together in packs for reasons of efficiency. You can read more about the repository layout [in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layouthttps://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are packed inside the `pack` and `idx` files.

You can run `git gc` on your original repository and your files will be packed as well.

---

#### !!! Not recommended

but you can use the following command to pack your repository

```
# Pack the current git repository
# --prune=now remove all unused objects
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```